# Como exibir o valor de String recuperada da sessão em JSF?

Tags: string, jsf, session, xhtml

estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar exibir, no xhtml, um valor String recuperado da sessão.
O que eu desejo é mostrar o valor de um atributo String (atributo nome) de um objeto da classe que criei (classe Usuario), o qual encontra-se armazenado na sessão.

O curioso é que:

1. se atribuo um **objeto** a uma chave do sessionMap, e tento recuperar um atributo string do objeto, o valor não é exibido.
2. se atribuo o valor de uma variável string à chave, o valor não é exibido.
3. se eu atribuo um valor literal string à chave, então o valor é exibido.

---

**Exemplo**:

*teste.xhtml*

Nas saídas s1 a s3, é exibido o nome da classe concatenado com o hash code do objeto.
Nas saídas s4 a s9, nada é exibido.
Na saída s10, a palavra *teste* é mostrada (o literal atribuído ao session map no LoginBean).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputText rendered="#{not empty usuarioLogado}"
        value=" 
        s1 #{usuarioLogado}
        s2 #{sessionScope.usuarioLogado}
        s3 #{sessionScope['usuarioLogado']}
        s4 #{usuarioLogado.nome}
        s5 #{sessionScope.usuarioLogado.nome}
        s6 #{sessionScope['usuarioLogado'].nome}
        s7 #{nomeUsuarioLogado}
        s8 #{sessionScope.nomeUsuarioLogado}            
        s9 #{sessionScope['usuarioLogado'].nome}
        s10 #{sessionScope.string_literal} ">
    </h:outputText>

</h:body>
</html>
```

*LoginBean.java*

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private Usuario usuario;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
    }

    public LoginBean() {

    }

    //getters and setters

    public String efetuarLogin(){

        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        boolean existeUsuario = new UsuarioDao(em).consultarUsuario(usuario);
        em.close();

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (existeUsuario) {
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("usuarioLogado", this.usuario);
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("nomeUsuarioLogado", this.usuario.getNome());
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("string_literal", "teste");

            return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

*Usuario.java*

```
public class Usuario {

    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private String email;

    public Usuario() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi a falha. O atributo **nome** estava vazio mesmo.
Na tela de login, informava-se apenas o **login** (username) e a **senha** do LoginBean.usuario, e esses dados eram utilizados como critérios para pesquisa no banco, por meio do método `UsuarioDao.consultarUsuario(Usuario)`. Mas, esse método retornava apenas um boolean.
A solução foi alterar o método `UsuarioDao.consultarUsuario(Usuario)`para que, em vez de um boolean, retornasse um objeto Usuario (ou null). Esse objeto, sim, totalmente populado, inclusive com o atributo nome.

O *LoginBean.java* ficou assim:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private Usuario usuario;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
    }

    public LoginBean() {

    }

    //getters and setters

    public String efetuarLogin(){

        EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
        this.usuario = new UsuarioDao(em).consultarUsuario(this.usuario);
        em.close();

        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (existeUsuario) {
            context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("usuarioLogado", this.usuario);

            return "index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }

        this.usuario = new Usuario();

        return null;
    }

}
```